# slick slider to show stacked slides

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, slick.js

I have implemented slick slider and is working great but it displays all the slides in 1 horizontal line.
For example I have 25-30 slides.
Currently I have set 5 slides to show at a time. If I increase it to 15 it shrinks the slides but stays in 1 horizontal line.
What I want is to have 3 rows each row containing 5 items. Meaning 1st slide contains 15 items in 3 rows(5 in each row) and the next slide shows remaining slides in same fashion.

**Example**
**Slide 1**
[image]

**Slide 2**
[image]

**Php Code**

```
<div class="slick_demo_2">
    <?php
    foreach ($boardPins as $boardPin)
    {
        ?>
        <div class="file-box">
            <div class="file">
                <a href="">
                    <span class="corner"></span>
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-folder " style="color: #1ab394"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-name text-center">
                                                <span class="badge badge-primary">
                                                    Text
                                                </span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.slick_demo_2').slick({
infinite: true,
slidesToShow: 3,
slidesToScroll: 1,
centerMode: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
Use rows setting in Js to create a grid design.

```
rows:3
```